# My bulb is permanently on. Why?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Setting: Victorian house, kitchen.

Light switch. 
1 red wire going into common. 
1 red wire going into L1

Original set up in the ceiling rose.
1 black wire, neutral.
2 red wires in the loop on the ceiling rose. 
1 red wire, live.

I recently changed my light fitting. I took all the wires out of the rose and connected them directly to a Habitat Fisherman light fitting.

It should have been simple.

Connect neutral to neutral. Earth to earth and live to live. Isolate the 2 remaining red wires into connectors.

I did that and the new light won't switch off. It's permanently on.

I tried changing the red wires in turn to figure out if i had connected the wrong red to red but there only seems to be one red wire that is live. 
(I haven't done a pro test using measuring tools)

I  took a picture of the rose just after I connected the first red wire to a connector. Originally this wire was in a loop position.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your one live red wire is (obviously) permanently live - so hooking that to your light will make it (obviously) permanently on.
The other 2 red wires are the ones running to your switch.
The live red needs to go to one of those switch wires, and the other switch wire (which will now be switched live) goes to your light.

Comment: Hi brhans. Thanks for the response. Are you saying I should connect  the permanent live and one of the other red wires to the live connector in the light fitting?

Comment: @user92424.  You don't need any extra dangling connectors, use the connectors in the base of the rose. Use two of the three "loop" connectors for your permanent live and one of the red pair, the other one of the red pair goes to the inner of the two-position connector et the end. The pendant cord wires go to the outermost connections.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RedGrittyBrick. It makes sense but I had to remove the ceiling rose in order to fit the bracket and canopy to the ceiling. I'm not sure how to go about connecting it all up without the Rose. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

To supplement what brhans says in his answer ...

Like this but without the middle cable (which is power to the *next* light & switch, not present in last ceiling rose on a circuit).

[image: wiring inside UK ceiling rose]

You have old colours - black instead of blue, red instead of brown.

Your electrician used the correct two-red cable for the switch, most electrician nowadays use the "normal" cable and put tape around the wrong-coloured wire to indicate it's actual purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RedGrittyBrick. It makes sense but I had to remove the ceiling rose in order to fit the bracket and canopy to the ceiling. I'm not sure how to go about connecting it all up without the Rose. Is it even possible?

Comment: @user92424 it is possible, you need to make the connections in a junction box  though. Have a look at, for example, Wagoboxes.

Comment: Thanks @RedGrittyBrick I'll have a go at that.